# Comparing 2 arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to build a result page for my work but I'm kind off stuck a.t.m.

I have 2 arrays and they need to be compared:

```
$dienstarray[] = $compdiensten['dienst'];
$userdienstarray[] = $userdiensten['dienst_id'];
```

And the outputs are:

$dienstarray:

```
Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => 9 [2] => 11 [3] => 12 [4] => 13 [5] => 22 [6] => 23 [7] => 24 [8] => 26 [9] => 27 [10] => 7 [11] => 25 )
```

$userdienstarray:

```
Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => 8 [2] => 9 )
```

$dienstarray needs to be compared with $userdienstarray and when a number is a match, the output is V and when it doesn't match the output has to be X

So in this example:

8 needs to be compared with $userdienstarray and in this case it's true, so V is being returned.

9 needs to be compared with $userdienstarray and in this case it's true, so V is being returned.

11 needs to be compared with $userdienstarray and in this case it's false, so X is being returned.

And so on.....

I hope you understand my question, if not please ask!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @moffeltje: FYI, that's what the downvote button is for,

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Easy, just trying to help OP making a better question.

Comment: Sure, but they aren't mutually exclusive. They both serve a purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work

```
$dienstarray[] = $compdiensten['dienst'];
$userdienstarray[] = $userdiensten['dienst_id'];
$result = 'X';
foreach ($dienstarray as $value) {
     if (in_array($value,$userdienstarray) {
         $result = 'V';
     }
}
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
  <?php
    $result = array_intersect($dienstarray, $userdienstarray);
    if(count($result) > 0 )
    echo 'V';
    else
    echo 'X';
    ?>
```

for individual matching try this

```
foreach ($dienstarray as $ar)
{
    if(in_array($ar, $userdienstarray))
    echo 'V';
    else 
    echo 'X';
}
```

Comment: if there is a number match in both array then it return V else X

Comment: yes but the numbers from $dienstarray need to be compared with $userdienstarray individually, I updated my post and added an answer to try to be clearer with my question.

Comment: updated my answer try with individual matching portion

Answer (score 0):

You mean, X if $userdienstarray contains values which are present in $dienstarray? 
Maybe:

```
function compareArrays($dienstarray, $userdienstarray) {
    foreach ($dienstarray as $element) {
        if (in_array($element, $userdienstarray)) {
            return "V";
        }
    }
    return "X";
}
```

Comment: I can't add this function because I need the output which is in a foreach loop already. PHP errors that compareArrays cannot be redeclared.

Comment: That error means you already have a function with the same name. You just need to change the name.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain it a bit better:

We have multiple companies and each company has it's own users.
In a database we have the table comp_diensten and user_diensten
In the table comp_diensten we have the services that company is allowed to use.
In the table user_diensten we have the services that are being used by company users.

This is my code:

```html
<?php
 if(!isset($_SESSION['y_logged'])){ include('../includes/no_access.php'); die(); }
 $users = new users();
 $compID = $_GET['comp'];
 
 if($_SESSION['y_status'] < 2){
  $checkComp = $users->check_if_comp_is_mine($_SESSION['y_resid'],$compID);
  if($checkComp == 0){ echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="'.REFRESH_DIRECT.';url='.$GLOBALS['site_info']['url'].'/beheer/bedrijven.html" />'; die(); }
 } else {
  $checkComp = $users->check_if_comp_exists($compID);
  if($checkComp == 0){ echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="'.REFRESH_DIRECT.';url='.$GLOBALS['site_info']['url'].'/beheer/bedrijven.html" />'; die(); }
 }
 
 $rapportage = $users->comp_rapportage($_GET['comp']);
?>
<div id="content_top_menu" style="padding:5px;">Rapportage overzicht</div>
<?php
 if($rapportage != 0){
  foreach($rapportage AS $key=>$rapportage){
   $showusers = $users->show_compusers($rapportage['id']);
   $compdiensten = $users->check_diensten($rapportage['id']);
   $dienstarray = array();
?>
<div class="table_wrapper" style="background-color:#E9E9E9;font-size:14px;">
 <div class="table_medium" style="border-right:1px solid #9B9EA0;"><strong><?php echo $rapportage['naam']; ?></strong></div>
 <?php
  foreach($compdiensten AS $key=>$compdiensten){
   $dienstNaam = $users->get_dienstnaam($compdiensten['dienst']);
   $dienstarray[] = $compdiensten['dienst'];
 ?>
 <div class="table_small" style="border-right:1px solid #9B9EA0;font-size:10px !important;width:6% !important;"><?php echo $dienstNaam['naam']; ?></div>
 <?php } ?>
</div>
<?php
 if($showusers == 0){
  echo 'Geen gebruikers gevonden';
 } else {
  foreach($showusers AS $key=>$showusers){
   $userdiensten = $users->check_userdiensten($showusers['id']);
   $userdienstarray = array();
   foreach($userdiensten AS $key=>$userdiensten){
    $userdienstarray[] = $userdiensten['dienst_id'];
   }
   // HERE we need the X or V
  }
 }
?>
<?php
 } } else {
?>
<div class="table_wrapper" style="background-color:#E9E9E9;font-size:14px;"><strong><?php echo $rapportage['naam']; ?></strong></div>
<?php } ?>
<div id="form_button_wrapper">
 <a href="<?php echo $GLOBALS['site_info']['url']; ?>/beheer/bedrijven.html" title="Ga terug naar klantenoverzicht" class="masterTooltip"><div class="form_submit_button">Terug</div></a>
</div>
```

I have put:
// HERE we need the X or V

In the code above